# Package python directory for different architectures

Tags: python, package, cython

I have a personal python library consisting of several modules of scientific programs that I use. These live on a directory with the structure:

```
root/__init__.py   
root/module1/__init__.py
root/module1/someprog.py
root/module1/ (...)
root/module2/__init__.py
root/module2/someprog2.py
root/module2/somecython.pyx
root/module2/somecython.so
root/module2/somefortran.f
root/module2/somefortran.so
(...)
```

I am constantly making changes to these programs and adding new files. With my current setup at work, I share the same directory with several machines of different architectures. What I want is a way to use these packages from python in the different architectures. If the packages were all pure python, this would be no problem. But the issue is that I have several compiled binaries (as shown in the example) from Cython and from f2py.

Is there a clever way to repackage these binaries so that python in the different systems only imports the relevant binaries? I'd like to keep the code organised in the same directory.

Obviously the simplest way would be to duplicate the directory or create another directory of symlinks. But this would mean that when new files are created, I'd have to update the symlinks manually.

Has anyone bumped into a similar problem, or can suggest a more pythonic approach to this organisation problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to do this. A python package must reside entirely in one directory. [PEP 382](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/) proposed support for namespace-packages that could be split in different directories, but it was rejected. (And in any case, those would be special packages.)

Given that python packages have to be in a single directory, it is not possible to mix compiled extension modules for different architectures. There are two ways to mitigate this problem:

1. Keep binary extensions on a separate directory, and have all the python packages in a common directory that can be shared between architectures. The separate directory for binary extension can then be selected for different architectures with `PYTHONPATH`.
2. Keep a common directory with all the python files and extensions for different architectures. For each architecture, create a new directory with the package name. Then symlink all the python files and binaries in each of these directories. This will still allow a single place where the code lives, at the expense of having to create new symlinks for each new file.

The option suggested by Thorsten Krans is unfortunately not viable for this problem. Using distutils/setuptools/distribute still requires all the python source files to be installed in a directory for each architecture, negating the advantage of having them in a single directory. (This is not a finished package, but always work in progress.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)/[distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute). You can then define a [setup.py](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) that compiles all files according to your current platform, copies them to some adequate directory and makes sure they are available in your `sys.path`.

Comment: But doesn't the setuptools way just put the package into different directories? What I wanted was a way to keep a centralised version of the source files (.py, .pyx, .f) and separate locations for the architecture-dependent files.

Answer (score 0):

You would do the following when you compile the source code of python.

Pass the exec-prefix flag with the directory to ./configure

For more info: ./configure --help will give you the following:

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

Hope this helps :)